# How to append html code to div element using Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I have a div and I have to add some html code that is in variable to that using Angular2.

```
import {Component,Input,ViewChild,ElementRef,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    template: `
    <div #myDiv>{{str}}</div>
`,
    styleUrls:['src/css/thedata.css']
})
    export class AngularComponent{
              private str = "<div class='EachWidget FL'><div class='WidgetDataParent'><div class='widgetTitleBar'></div></div></div>";

         }
```

I have to add str string as html in div named myDiv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to the `innerHTML` attribute like this:

```js
import {Component,Input,ViewChild,ElementRef,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="str" #myDiv></div>
`,
    styleUrls:['src/css/thedata.css']
})
export class AngularComponent{
    private str = "<div class='EachWidget FL'><div class='WidgetDataParent'><div class='widgetTitleBar'></div></div></div>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another doubt. I have added a div through innerHTML and that has a (click) function. But when I click that it's not working.`private str = "<div class='EachWidget FL'><div class='WidgetDataParent' (click)="widget_click($event)"><div class='widgetTitleBar'></div></div></div>";`

Comment: Yes, this won't work. You can only have event bindings on **real** template code.

Comment: You can however dynamically add components - have a look at this: http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/

Comment: Technically, innerHtml does not append, it replaces the html.

Comment: Despite OP using the wrong verb here, you can guess what he meant by looking at his code.

Comment: another way, look at this:
http://alisch.me/post/Add-Component-dynamically-in-Angular-2